# JessTab: Finding average value

Tags: protege, jess

I am trying to find the average age of the people asserted in the family ontology by the following JessTab rule:

```
(defrule print_people_total_age 
   (object (https://wiki.csc.calpoly.edu/OntologyTutorial/family_example.owl#age ?a1)) 
   => 
   (bind ?s 0) 
   (bind ?num 0) 
   (foreach ?a (create$ ?a1) (+ ?s ?a) (++ ?num) (printout t "Total age " ?s " and average age is " (/ ?s ?num) " of persons" crlf)))
```

The rule compiles well, but when activated errors this:

```
Jess reported an error in routine +
    while executing (+ ?s ?a)
    while executing (foreach ?a (create$ ?a1) (+ ?s ?a) (++ ?num) (printout t "Total age " ?s " and average age is " (/ ?s ?num) " of persons" crlf))
    while executing defrule MAIN::print_people_total_ageSSS
    while executing (run).
  Message: Not a number: "~@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer 20".
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the basics of rule execution, most notably that each fact (or set of facts) that matches a rule results in an execution of this rule and ***all of these executions are independent from each other.*** To combine data contained in several facts you may use the accumulate CE; in more complex situation an auxiliary fact may be required.

```
(defrule sumofages
?res <- (accumulate (progn (bind ?s 0)(bind ?n))
                    (progn (bind ?s (+ ?s ?a)) (++ ?n))
                    (create$ ?n ?s)
                    (object (age ?a)))
=>
(bind ?s (nth$ 2 ?res))
(bind ?n (nth$ 1 ?res))
(printout t "Total age " ?s
            " and average age is " (/ ?s ?n) " of persons" crlf))
```

You should also make sure to understand the basic workings of the arithmetic functions. `(+ ?s ?a)?` adds but changes neither operand.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I think there is a syntactic issue on your rule (it does not run). Maybe it's on the initialization on ?n variable. I tried with (bind ?n 0) but failed.

Comment: Somehow I lost a couple of parentheses during the copy-paste. Should be OK now - the rule was tested.

Comment: I am testing with the following (family ontology) [https://wiki.csc.calpoly.edu/OntologyTutorial/raw-attachment/wiki/AddingRuleWithJessTab/family_example_for_rules.owl] in JessTab in Protege 3.5. The rule compiles well if I give initial value 0 to ?n, but when executing no result is produced. I can observe that in the Rule tab the variable ?a of the rule has changed to ?_20_a(1,30,0) in its first appearance and ?_20_a in the second one.

Comment: OK it works. The problem was with the family ontology. I modified it to be clear for Protege and the rule fires correctly

Comment: Why I must first execute (reset) before (run) to get the rule fire? If I execute (run) after publishing the rule it will print 0, but when I first (reset) and than run the rule will fire correctly. (maybe) This happens only with rules containing accumulate in LHS.

Comment: I'd need to see all of your clp to give you the correct answer. Check for yourself: "**Description:** Removes all facts from working memory, removes all activations, then asserts the fact (initial-fact), then asserts all facts found in deffacts, asserts a fact representing each registered Java object, and (if the set-reset-globals property is TRUE) initializes all defglobals." - Quoted from the Jess manual, which may be read, free of charge :-)

Comment: You can test it with the family example

Comment: Well, I'm not going to dig into protege and family what-not, sorry. Most likely, it's some deffacts that have to be put into working memory. You can use some API method to check what the WM contains before you call reset.